# Inherited views in Rails 3.1 - instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can an inherited view template know what the (main) instance variable name is? Is there:

- some built-in way to detect them using some magic, or;
- we roll our
  own (with the controller name is the only method I can think of right
  now), or;
- use some generic name, or;
- ???

Rolling my own right now, but if the wheel's already been invented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some reading and experimentation, I found out that it has the same helpers as [`inherited_resource_views`](https://github.com/fredwu/inherited_resources_views)

- `collection` to get the collection (eg. index action)
- `resource` to get the resource (eg. show action)

And the resource(s) are still available as instance variables (eg. `@user` in `UsersController`)